# Can't login as user after upgrade 12.04 to 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, upgrade, login, users

After upgrade I can't log in.
Error message:

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

This is on a system with 2 partitions. This installation is on `/dev/sda5` type `ext4`.
Could this partition be read only? Maybe because of an error?
If so, how can I repair this partition?
BTW, I can login as guest.

Help highly appreciated...

Update 
User login works if I use recovery mode. 
Also, the partition is shown as read only. I can change this using the recovery console, but it looks like it changes back to read only if I'm returning to normal boot process out of the console. 
I tried to repair the partition with 
sudo rack.ext4 -v -f /dev/sda5 
( a command I found somewhere, without really knowing what I'm doing) but the results didn't show an error. –

Comment: Can you get in with recovery mode?

Comment: Yes, user login works if a use recovery mode. Also, the partition is shown as read only. I can change this using the recovery console, but it looks like it changes back to read only if I'm returning to normal boot process out of the console. I tried to repair the partition with sudo rack.ext4 -v -f /dev/sda5 ( a command I found somewhere, without really knowing what I'm doing) but the results didn't show an error.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself. (And you **can** delete your own comments, no need for duplicates)

Comment: Tried to use the suggested answer in the possible duplicate. Didn't work. But then I am not 100% sure that the commands actually did the intended changes to the ICEauthority ownership.